# modrewrite internal redirect to convert folders into querystring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

Good day all.
I've written a very basic redirect to handle the querystring and foldernames in the URL.

actually my code is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /product-detail\.html\?intid=([^&]+)&name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /product-detail/%2/%3/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?product-detail/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /product-detail.php?intid=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

It seems pretty straight forward, but once I make a request like:

```
http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/product-detail.html?intid=1234&name=pippo
```

I get redirected to:

```
http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/product-detail/1234/pippo/
```

which is fine, but I got also this error:

```
The requested URL /product-detail/1234/pippo/ was not found on this server.
```

Now, the second rule seems correct to me, I really do not understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. In my test environment, it is redirected properly. Maybe `product-detail.php` doesn't exist, or there's a mismatch between `product-detail.html` and `product-detail.php`.

Comment: actually that is not a mismatch, I'd like to have the request done on the "html" file, but in the end the code will be on a php file.

Comment: That was just an idea. Then there's something else. As I mentioned, your rules work for me.